# Does sitecore output cache caches whole image

Tags: sitecore

I'm setting up the output caching for sitecore with guide provided on SDN.

I've ticked the cacheable and clear on index update and by Data options.

However I noticed that every hard refresh, the full image gets requested i.e. 4 MB.

IS this a an expected behaviour?

Comment: *"every hard refresh, the full image gets requested i.e. 4 MB"* — do you mean that it gets requested by the browser?

Comment: Erm... what did you expect a hard refresh to do? The browser needs to get the image from the server somehow... maybe you should reconsider usage of images that large or re-scale the image using height/width parameters in Sitecore.

Comment: @Myagdi did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output cache stores generated html instead of executing the process of rendering your component.

It has nothing to do with sending images and caching them in browser cache.

Read [How the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS Caches Output](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/09/how-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms-caches-output.aspx) JW blog post for more details and see the links in comments.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume that by saying "hard refresh" you mean [bypassing your browser cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache).

What you are seeing is not specific to Sitecore, or any server-side technology. It is your browser that uses caching to keep local copies of images and other "static" resources that it has loaded in the past. This cache is used to speed up page loads and reduce network traffic.

When you perform a hard refresh, the browser will ignore its cache and load all resources from the server. This is why there's a request to your image after a hard refresh.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a normal behaviour.
Sitecore stores all media cache to file system, unlike all other caches, stored in RAM. Media items are stored in in database, so media cache is required to reduce database calls and serve media files faster to end-user. Let's understand Sitecore media cache mechanism.

Please check next link for details: http://sitecoreblog.patelyogesh.in/2014/04/how-sitecore-media-cache-is-works.html